# how do i disable a certain javascript on iphone/ipad or other mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, ipad, mobile-safari

I got this for IE browsers,

```
var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;

if (IE) {
    // IE.
} else {
    // Others.
}
```

but how would i do the same for iphone/ipad/mobiledevices?
(do not want to redirect to another page on any mobile devices)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to check the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string as follows:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
   // iPad or iPhone
}
else {
   // Anything else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be a bit of a problem because every app makes its own Header. My apache server gets this as Browser: [APPNAME]/1.0_CFNetwork/459_Darwin/10.3.0

You could search for Darwin, but I don't know if this is waterproof.

A JS-Snippet should look like that:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)
{
   document.write('You're using Mozilla Firefox');
}
```

Comment: It's probably best not to check for "Darwin"; Darwin is the system that runs not only iPhone OS, but also Mac OS X. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)